# Elastic search returning no results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have Elasticsearch demonstrating counterintuitive behaviour. This is reproducible with the following steps

1) Add a document

```
curl -XPUT 'http://myelasticseach:1234/anindex/atype/1' -d '
{
  obj1: 
  {
    foo : "bar"
  },
  obj2 : 
  {
    baz : "qux"
  }
}'
```

2) Search for 'bar'. I expect and get 1 result

```
curl -XGET 'http://myelasticseach:1234/anindex/_search?q=bar'
```

3) Search for 'qux'. I expect and get 1 result

```
curl -XGET 'http://myelasticseach:1234/anindex/_search?q=qux'
```

4) Update document

```
curl -XPUT 'http://myelasticseach:1234/anindex/atype/1' -d '
{
  atype: 
  {
    foo : "bar"
  },
  obj2 : 
  {
    baz : "qux"
  }
}'
```

5) Search for 'bar'. I expect and get 1 result

```
curl -XGET 'http://myelasticseach:1234/anindex/_search?q=bar'
```

6) Sarch for 'qux'. I expect 1 result, but get 0???

```
curl -XGET 'http://myelasticseach:1234/anindex/_search?q=qux'
```

Why when the nested object in the document has a key matching the type of the document can I no longer get results from the rest of the objects with keys that do not match the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue in elasticsearch 0.90.0.

See 'Wrong mapping using a nested object with same name as its type'
https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues/3005